# Change $state in AngularJS from Browser Console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wish to do a state change from the browser console.

Is there any way to fire the `$state.go` function from the console itself.

Do note that the states do not have a url defined hence I cannot use that to hit a state.

I require this for quicker debugging of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a breakpoint and stop your code somewhere $state is injected, so you can use it. Or you can simply inject it into your .run() and assign it to the window object so you can run it from anywhere anytime...

Comment: as in 

`angular.module('app').run(function($state) {  window.$state = $state; }); `

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do you will get $state is not defined

```
 suppose you write $state.go('landing.home');
```

because $state is defined within controller provide you have injected $state in controller, instance of $state is not available outside controller

Even if you want to route through console you can do one thing

Open console but breakpoint somewhere inside controller then write

```
$state.go('landing.home');
```

this way it will work and route to required page